# How check mouseover on two elements ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need hide tooltip on mouseout of link, BUT not if mouseover on tooltip (both have different parents)
For example: we can see it on Facebook when hover on names or avatars  friends

I try this but every time i get FALSE

```
$('a').bind('mouseleave', function () {   
      var i = $('div.tooltip').is('hover');
      if(i===true){
      console.log('cursor over the tooltip, so dont hide');
      }
      else{
      console.log('hide tooltip');
      }   
});
```

How i can check both condition?

Comment: You must use ':hover' selector instead of 'hover' (with semicolon). also can try to use event.relativeTarget property of event-object

Comment: Please check this out, http://jqapi.com/#p=hover

Answer (score 1):

Put both the link and the tool tip in the same parent:

```
<div id="parent">
    <a href="link.com">link</a>
    <div id="tooltip">tooltip</div>
</div>
```

And then in the script you can just put the mouseleave function on the parent:

```
$("#parent a").mouseenter(function(){
   $("#tooltip").css("display","block"); //or however you handle this
});
$("#parent").mouseleave(function(){
   $("#tooltip").css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: it would be too easy ) I just cant. i have too many links and only one div for tooltip where i load different data for all links.

Comment: is that div always the same size?  How are you handling the tooltip visible/invisible?

Comment: if you can't change that, i would recommend looking at adeneo's answer below

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change your markup, use a timed event and abort it when the mouse enter either element, like so:

```
var timer;

$("a, .tooltip").mouseleave(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(doSomething, 10);
}).mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
});

function doSomething() {
    console.log('hide tooltip');
}
```

[Here's a FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/CunWL/)